# Action Controller::Connection not established while creating an application in ruby on rails with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an application in ruby on rails along with mysql connection.I have followed the given steps below to do that.

`rails new ProjectName -d mysql`

1. Uninstall your myslq2 gem: `$gem uninstall mysql2`
2. Reinstall the mysql2 gem with path option: `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector"'`
3. Copy the libmysql.dll you find in `C:\mysql-connector\lib` into `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin`
4. Open in your rails app the file "Gemfile" and edit it enabling the mysql2, by adding: `gem 'mysql2'`
5. Start your rails server: `$rails server`
6. Open your browser and go to `localhost:3000/`

But when i'm running the server in the browser window i'm getting the following error.

```
Action Controller::Connection not established while creating an application in ruby on rails with mysql
```

And my config/database.yml looks like this

```
default: &default  
adapter: mysql2 
encoding: utf8
database: mp_development  
pool: 5  
username: root  
password: qwe123 
host: localhost


development:
  <<: *default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8  
database: mp_development
pool: 5
username: root
password: qwe123
host: localhost
```

Could someone tell the solution ASAP. Thank you in advance

Comment: post your `config/database.yml` in your question

Comment: Can you confirm your username password and see if you have `mp_development` database exists.

Comment: It's not a solution, but to avoid your future headaches install at least a virtualbox that will run ubuntu and do your development in linux environment. Or do as I did, dual boot with windows and ubuntu. Good luck.

Comment: how to check whether the mp_development database exist?

Comment: You can refer to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25831665/1047207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, rectify your database.yml syntax:

```
default: &default  
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8
  database: mp_development  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password: qwe123 
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
  database: mp_production
```

After that, make sure your refereed database exists, run:

```
rake db:setup # it will create db, if not exists
```

Now try to run your server and browse the application.

Answer (score 0):

> Action Controller::Connection not established while creating an application in ruby on rails with mysql

***You need to start your mysql server to get rid of this error***, if you are using mac then you can do it by running **mysql.server start** in your terminal. If you are **using windows then you can start your server by following [`these commands`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html)**. Run these commands after starting your server:

- rake db:create - It will create your database mp_development.
- rake db:migrate - It will run your migration files

**Update:**
If you look at your error it says

> Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces.

***YAML files are sensitive to the spacing issues so just make sure all the values are properly indented.*** Change your database.yml to this:

```
default: &default  
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8 
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password: qwe123 
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default 
  database: mp_development
```

Comment: if i run the command rake db:create it's showing rake aborted!
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/myproj/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 39 column 1. what error is this?? what should i do for this?? @Mandeep

Comment: @PriyaDharshini check update. I have also removed duplicate code for development environment